# Why is the term "Know" used between Adam and Chava?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, marriage, parashat-bereishit, adam, eve-chava

Why does the Torah refer to the process of Adam having children with Chava as "knowing" her? ([Bereishis 4:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.4.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> וְהָאָדָם יָדַע אֶת־חַוָּה אִשְׁתּוֹ וַתַּהַר וַתֵּלֶד אֶת־קַיִן
>   וַתֹּאמֶר קָנִיתִי אִישׁ אֶת־יְהוָה׃
>
> Now the man knew his wife Eve, and she conceived and bore Cain,
>   saying, “I have gained a male child with the help of the LORD.”

Comment: To expand, almost all marital relations in the Torah use the verb “know”.

Comment: On a simple level, “to know” is the common Biblical euphemism for marital relations.

Comment: @LN6595 Right, my question is how the word "knowing" is connected to marital relations - but focused on just Adam and Chava since it's the first place it's mentioned